# Salesforce Auth Provider - Not working

Tags: facebook, salesforce

We have an integration which was working till 2nd Sep 2014 and all of a sudden it stopped working. Doing some further R&D we found that we are not able to add a new Auth Provider now. When we do that we get an error saying: Error autocreating Apex Class: Invalid type: Auth.UserData

When we try to edit and save the Handler of our existing Auth Provider (without making any changes) we get an error saying : Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: Auth.UserData at line 2 column 41

Seems like something got changed on that date, any one facing the similar issue?

Comment: Turned out that we created a class named "Auth" in that Org. Salesforce Auth Provider functionality started referring to our class instead of Salesforce class. Changing the class name fixed the issue.